Hibernate generating N(N+1) Updates for each Insert
On Hibernate 6.4.4 and 6.4.9, I am observing the following odd behavior.
In a loop, I am doing the following:
for (loop control) {
  SomeObject object = new SomeObject(contents);
  repository.saveAndFlush(object);
  entityManager.detach(object);
}

At runtime, I am seeing the following in my log at each iteration of the loop:
First:
Hibernate: insert into some_object ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...

Second:
Hibernate: insert into some_object ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...

Third:
Hibernate: insert into some_object ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...
Hibernate: update some_object set ...

And so on. By the 100th record, the process has slowed to a crawl. I understand that I might have better luck with saveAll, but at this time I have to do these in a loop. This issue happens if I do a save() rather than a saveAndFlush(), and also happens if I detach or not.
What could be causing this, and what’s the best way to approach a fix? Of note, the two updates per insert are livable; it’s the increasing updates for each turn that are the problem.
